# Where does system-address-book pull data from?

Tags: evolution

I can see many contacts in my `gnome-contacts`, but I have no idea where the contacts is being pulled from.

I installed folks-tools and ran `folks-inspect` and then `persona-stores`. There, I found out that some system-address-book has the data with the type-id eds ( evolution-data-server ), that is responsible for maintaining mail, calendar, addressbook, tasks and memo information. This database as seen by the output has a set of 1955 personas. But I am unable to find the source of the database. Can anyone please help?

```
Persona store 'system-address-book' with 1955 personas:
  display-name          Personal
  id                    system-address-book
  is-writeable          FALSE
  trust-level           FOLKS_PERSONA_STORE_TRUST_FULL
  is-primary-store      TRUE
  is-user-set-default   TRUE
  type-id               eds
  can-add-personas      FOLKS_MAYBE_BOOL_TRUE
  can-alias-personas    FOLKS_MAYBE_BOOL_FALSE
  can-group-personas    FOLKS_MAYBE_BOOL_TRUE
  can-remove-personas   FOLKS_MAYBE_BOOL_TRUE
  is-prepared           TRUE
  always-writeable-properties  { 'local-ids', 'web-service-addresses', 'gender', 'is-favourite', 'anti-links', 'extended-info', 'full-name', 'structured-name', 'nickname', 'email-addresses', 'postal-addresses', 
  is-quiescent          TRUE
  personas              Set of 1955 personas
  source                0x7f783c016a20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contacts database of 1955 personas is stored as contacts.db in

~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system/contacts.db

Similarly mail, calendar, tasks and memo can be found under ~/.local/share/evolution

This is similiar to the thunderbird profile where every user data is stored under one folder. However, it looks like the profile for evolution data is a fixed path under the home directory and cannot be changed. The thunderbird profile can be put anywhere on the disk and controlled from ~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini